# Uploading and downloading file from ONEDRIVE through WCF service

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a task to Upload and Download a word file from the microsoft ONEdrive using WCF service. I there is a possiblity to do that. Can doing the authentication through WCF service is easy without the interaction with user. Everything should be done in the background.

Regards,

Rajesh

Comment: Have you done any research on this?  If so, what did you find and what was unclear?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have done extensive research on this. But what ever the solution I got is like there is user interaction to give credentials to get the authentication code. I am not able to find whether there is any way to actually provide credentials in the background without User interaction. USER should not know that he is accessing ONEDRIVE for editing the word document.

Comment: In my ASP.NET MVC application User don't know that he is editing the word document from the ONEDRIVE.  So When he click a button called EDIT, in the background a word document which is there on the server will be uploaded on to the ONEDRIVE by the WCF service and somehow the link for the WORD document is provided to the CLIENT and user edits it and once it is done , the WCF service should download it back to the server. This is my Scenario. So in this scenario the authentication process should be done in the background With out the user interaction.

Any insights on this??